# how to get image orientation to rotate 270 degrees (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, orientation, pi

Right now this code will only rotate my image 90 degrees. I can not figure out how to rotate it 270 degrees.

```
        transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with some basic math.

360° = 2π. 180° = π. 90° = π/2. 270° = 3π/2.

This means your posted code is rotating 180 degrees.

Use `Double.pi/2` for 90° and `3*Double.pi/2` for 270°.

Comment: double.pi/2 does not displaying anything neither does, 3*Double.pi/2. The only thing I can get to display the image is by typing in double.pin.

Comment: When you use `transform.rotated(by:)` you are increasing the current rotation by the specified amount.

Comment: I changed the name of the function but that did not do anything if i write 3*Double.pi/2. The image will not be displayed.