# Rotating image by 3*Double.pi/2 makes image not appear (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, rotation, orientation

Trying to rotate my image orientation by 270 degrees I can rotate by 90 degrees and the image appears however when rotating the image by 270 nothing happens. I have added 2 pictures of the 90 and 270 degrees commands to make things more clear.

```
extension CIImage {
var image: UIImage? { return UIImage(ciImage: self) }
var rotatingLeft: CIImage? {
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: extent.midX, y: extent.midY)
        .rotated(by: CGFloat.pi.divided(by: 2))
        .translatedBy(x: -extent.midX, y: -extent.midY)
    return CIFilter(name: "CIAffineTransform", withInputParameters: [kCIInputImageKey: self, kCIInputTransformKey: NSValue(cgAffineTransform: transform)])?.outputImage
}
var rotatingRight: CIImage? {
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: extent.midX, y: extent.midY)
        .rotated(by: -CGFloat.pi.divided(by: 2))
        .translatedBy(x: -extent.midX, y: -extent.midY)
    return CIFilter(name: "CIAffineTransform", withInputParameters: [kCIInputImageKey: self, kCIInputTransformKey: NSValue(cgAffineTransform: transform)])?.outputImage
}
}

extension UIImage {
var ciimage: CIImage? { return CIImage(image: self) }
}





import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate   {
@IBOutlet var displayImage: UIImageView!


var currentImageView: UIImageView?

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    self.currentImageView?.image = displayImage.image

    self.currentImageView?.image = image.ciimage?.rotatingLeft?.image

    self.dismiss(animated: true)


}

    func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
        if let error = error {
            // we got back an error!
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            present(ac, animated: true)
        } else {

            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Image Saved!", message: "Your image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            present(ac, animated: true)
        }
    }

@IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: Any) {



    self.currentImageView = self.displayImage



    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self


    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}}
```

[image]

Comment: Since you already asked this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43619944/how-to-get-image-orientation-to-rotate-270-degrees-swift3) and accepted (what I believe) to be a good answer, what is the issue? Why are you repeatedly asking the same question? Maybe you have a different problem than what you think?

Comment: Your right but I did not test the code before I awarded the answer. 3 * double.pi /2 does not produce a image. You can see that in my 2nd picture.

Comment: The rotation happens on one of the corners, not the center. So it rotatea out of view.

Comment: That makes sense. How can I set the rotation to the center and rotate the image by 270 degrees.

Comment: I highly recommend you read https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html

Comment: Ok I will check it out. But what I am asking is it possible?

Comment: Rotation is possible of course. You probably just need to also apply the needed translation to keep in view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend CIImage instead of UIImage and use core image filter CIAffineTransform using the transformation matrix. Start translating it to the center, rotate it 90 degrees (.pi/2) and move it back:

```
extension CIImage {
    var image: UIImage? { return UIImage(ciImage: self) }
    func rotated(_ angle: CGFloat) -> CIImage? {
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: extent.midX, y: extent.midY)
            .rotated(by: angle * .pi /  180)
            .translatedBy(x: -extent.midX, y: -extent.midY)
        return CIFilter(name: "CIAffineTransform", withInputParameters: [kCIInputImageKey: self, kCIInputTransformKey: NSValue(cgAffineTransform: transform)])?.outputImage
    }
    var rotatedLeft: CIImage? { return rotated(90) }
    var rotatedRight: CIImage? { return rotated(-90) }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let image = UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string:"https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs4RX.jpg")!))!
image.ciimage?.rotated(22.5)?.image
image.ciimage?.rotatedRight?.image
image.ciimage?.rotatedLeft?.image
```

Comment: This is close but does not produce the desired result in my code. I have tried this in the playground file and it works perfectly. However my code takes a image and places it in the image view. The photo not the image view is what I am trying to rotate. I have added all of my code and what your added code produces. Your code in my code produces a image flipped 180 degrees and is cropped. Thanks again for all of your help.

Comment: I have tested it here and the solution is to create a climate property and store the image and apply the rotation there and update the imageView with an UIImage from it