# Swift 3 rotate image Z-axis

Tags: swift, rotation, uiimage

Does anyone know rotate image on Z-axis?

Y-axis direction up in swift

link on [rotate(by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcontext/1456228-rotate)

On example rotate on 30 degrees

```
context.rotate(by: 0.5)
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9uDk.png)

Comment: Usually a Z axis is a third dimension, or if there are layered views (images?) , it's the *order* of them (note the plural). I can't envision a *single* image 30 degrees affecting the *order*, so maybe you are thinking something like *CIPerspectiveTransform*? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIPerspectiveTransform

Comment: I want to rotate UIImage on 90 degrees but when i rotate image it doesn't appear. And i come to decision that Y-axis direction up. Is may be this bug?

Comment: Ah. You're probably looking for *CIAffineTransform*. This answer should get you on the right track (it's asking for a 270 degree rotation but I think the answer also addresses 90 degrees):https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43646321/rotating-image-by-3double-pi-2-makes-image-not-appear-swift3

Comment: i found solve. Thank you very much!!!