# Swift: Rotate UIImageView from fixed position to full screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, snapkit

I want to rotate a view. Tried different things but can not make it

I use autolayout.
As a result I have imageView in the top of the screen with share almost as a square

```
        func presentPortrait() {
        coverImageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        coverImageView.snp.remakeConstraints { (make) in
        make.leading.trailing.top.equalToSuperview()         
        make.width.equalTo(coverImageView.snp.height).multipliedBy(375.0/211.0)
    }



    func presentLandscape() {               
    coverImageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(.pi/2), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    coverImageView.snp.remakeConstraints { (make) in
    make.leading.trailing.top.bottom.equalToSuperview()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing enough details. (1) Are these images supposed to be what you *want* or what *is happening*? (2) Are you using auto-layout constraints or frames? Trust me, **both** questions matter.

Comment: @dfd updated, check it please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43647520/2303865

Comment: its not about uiimage....

Comment: @dsfs it would easier for you to use CABasicAnimation

Comment: @dsfs what is snp?

Comment: BTW why don't you just rotate the image inside your image view, so you dont have to care about the autolayout?